# Add and remove words from the NLTK stopwords list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, nltk

I'm trying to add and remove words from the NLTK stopwords list:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))

#add words that aren't in the NLTK stopwords list
new_stopwords = ['cette', 'les', 'cet']
new_stopwords_list = set(stop_words.extend(new_stopwords))

#remove words that are in NLTK stopwords list
not_stopwords = {'n', 'pas', 'ne'} 
final_stop_words = set([word for word in new_stopwords_list if word not in not_stopwords])

print(final_stop_words)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_stop.py", line 10, in <module>
new_stopwords_list = set(stop_words.extend(new_stopwords))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))

#add words that aren't in the NLTK stopwords list
new_stopwords = ['cette', 'les', 'cet']
new_stopwords_list = stop_words.union(new_stopwords)

#remove words that are in NLTK stopwords list
not_stopwords = {'n', 'pas', 'ne'} 
final_stop_words = set([word for word in new_stopwords_list if word not in not_stopwords])

print(final_stop_words)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update` instead of `extend` and replace this line `new_stopwords_list = set(stop_words.extend(new_stopwords))` in this way:

```
stop_words.update(new_stopwords)
new_stopwords_list = set(stop_words)
```

By the way, it can be confusing if you call a `set` with a name which contains the word `list`

Answer (score 1):

Do `list(set(...))` insted of `set(...)` because only lists have an method called `extend`:

```
...
stop_words = list(set(stopwords.words('french')))
...
```